# How to transfer RSA public[/private] key outside the card?

Tags: javacard

I wrote the below simple program to generate a RSA key pair and transfer the public key to outside the card in the APDU response:

```java
public class CryptoRSA extends Applet {

    //Abbreviations
    private static final boolean NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS = false;

    //Switch case parameters for selecting instruction =  INS in apdu command
    private static final byte GENERATE_KEY_PAIR = (byte) 0xC0;


    //Create object of keys
    RSAPrivateKey thePrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PRIVATE, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_512, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
    RSAPublicKey thePublickKey = (RSAPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PUBLIC, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_512, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
    KeyPair theKeyPair = new KeyPair(thePublickKey, thePrivateKey);

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new CryptoRSA();
    }

    protected CryptoRSA() {
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        short privateKeySize = 0;
        short publicKeySize = 0;
        byte[] publicArray;
        byte[] privateArray;
        try {
            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

                case GENERATE_KEY_PAIR:

                    theKeyPair.genKeyPair();

                    PrivateKey thePrivateKey = theKeyPair.getPrivate();
                    PublicKey thePublicKey = theKeyPair.getPublic();

                    publicKeySize = thePrivateKey.getSize();
                    privateKeySize = thePrivateKey.getSize();

                    byte[] publicKey = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) (publicKeySize), JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
                    ((RSAPublicKey) thePrivateKey).getExponent(publicKey, (short) publicKeySize);

                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(publicKey, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, (short) (publicKeySize ));
                    apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) (publicKeySize));
                    break;

                default:
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof CryptoException) {
                short r = ((CryptoException) e).getReason();
                ISOException.throwIt(r);
            } else {
                ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x8888);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But when I send the related APDU command to the card, I receive `0x8888` as below:

```java
OSC:: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a40400060102030405dd -s 00c00000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 DD
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C0 00 00
Received (SW1=0x88, SW2=0x88)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `getSize()` returns the bit length of the key, not the byte length. You are probably running out of RAM.

2.`((RSAPublicKey) thePrivateKey).getExponent(publicKey, (short) publicKeySize);`

This won't work! You are asking for the exponent to be stored at offset `publicKeySize` in array `publicKey` -- that is, at the very end of the array, where there are precisely 0 bytes left to store it.

By the way, the next time you come across a problem like this you can use `ISOException` to send debugging data to the outside world. For instance, `ISOException.throwIt(privateKeySize)` would have found problem 1.